# automatic regular data retrieval from SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am developing a website performance monitoring tool, that measures the website performance of user website.

I want to automate the process...meaning the information (like URL of the user) is automatically retrieved from the SQL server database in regular intervals.  Say 1 hrs, 2 hrs, whatever and insert the data measured into the database. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want to setup a [TSQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void PeriodicUpdate()
{      
     System.Timers.Timer time = new System.Timers.Timer();
     time.Elapsed += time_Elapsed;
     time.Start();                
     time.Interval = //Set your time interval. Its in milliseconds   
     time.AutoReset = true;            

}

private void time_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Write your task here.
}
```